# Python/Beautifulsoup - Missing first row of table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Could someone please help me understand why the output for the below code is missing the first row of the table? I'm new to python, and not for lack of trying, I haven't been able to troubleshoot this myself.

```
import requests
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq


def printfunction():
    with open("C:/Users/.../audusd.csv", 'a', newline='') as f:
        wr = csv.writer(f)
        wr.writerows([(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5])])


url = requests.get("https://au.investing.com/currencies/aud-usd-historical-data/",
                   headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

od = OrderedDict()
content_page = soup(url.content, 'html.parser')
table = content_page.find('table', {'class': 'genTbl closedTbl historicalTbl'})
cols = [th.text for th in table.select("th")[1:]]

for row in table.select("tr + tr"):
 data = [td.text for td in row.select("td")]
 printfunction()
 print(data)
```

Output appears thus:

```
['Aug 23, 2018', '0.7246', '0.7349', '0.7355', '0.7240', '-1.37%']
['Aug 22, 2018', '0.7347', '0.7370', '0.7371', '0.7332', '-0.33%']
['Aug 21, 2018', '0.7371', '0.7341', '0.7383', '0.7332', '0.42%']
['Aug 20, 2018', '0.7340', '0.7306', '0.7344', '0.7294', '0.44%']
['Aug 19, 2018', '0.7308', '0.7316', '0.7317', '0.7308', '-0.05%']
['Aug 17, 2018', '0.7312', '0.7261', '0.7321', '0.7253', '0.70%']
['Aug 16, 2018', '0.7261', '0.7240', '0.7288', '0.7222', '0.30%']
['Aug 15, 2018', '0.7239', '0.7247', '0.7249', '0.7202', '-0.08%']
['Aug 14, 2018', '0.7245', '0.7270', '0.7284', '0.7222', '-0.33%']
['Aug 13, 2018', '0.7269', '0.7289', '0.7300', '0.7248', '-0.25%']
['Aug 12, 2018', '0.7287', '0.7278', '0.7300', '0.7273', '-0.21%']
['Aug 10, 2018', '0.7302', '0.7372', '0.7381', '0.7279', '-0.95%']
['Aug 09, 2018', '0.7372', '0.7435', '0.7456', '0.7371', '-0.81%']
['Aug 08, 2018', '0.7432', '0.7420', '0.7440', '0.7382', '0.15%']
['Aug 07, 2018', '0.7421', '0.7386', '0.7440', '0.7379', '0.46%']
['Aug 06, 2018', '0.7387', '0.7398', '0.7406', '0.7372', '-0.09%']
['Aug 05, 2018', '0.7394', '0.7397', '0.7400', '0.7394', '-0.08%']
['Aug 03, 2018', '0.7400', '0.7359', '0.7412', '0.7346', '0.54%']
['Aug 02, 2018', '0.7360', '0.7405', '0.7413', '0.7354', '-0.59%']
['Aug 01, 2018', '0.7404', '0.7427', '0.7430', '0.7389', '-0.34%']
['Jul 31, 2018', '0.7429', '0.7408', '0.7442', '0.7402', '0.30%']
['Jul 30, 2018', '0.7407', '0.7390', '0.7416', '0.7387', '0.12%']
['Jul 29, 2018', '0.7398', '0.7400', '0.7406', '0.7398', '-0.04%']
['Jul 27, 2018', '0.7401', '0.7377', '0.7416', '0.7369', '0.31%']
['Jul 26, 2018', '0.7378', '0.7456', '0.7464', '0.7370', '-1.03%']
['Jul 25, 2018', '0.7455', '0.7424', '0.7466', '0.7391', '0.46%']
```

Desired output (as per source table):

```
['Aug 24, 2018', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
['Aug 23, 2018', '0.7246', '0.7349', '0.7355', '0.7240', '-1.37%']
['Aug 22, 2018', '0.7347', '0.7370', '0.7371', '0.7332', '-0.33%']
['Aug 21, 2018', '0.7371', '0.7341', '0.7383', '0.7332', '0.42%']
['Aug 20, 2018', '0.7340', '0.7306', '0.7344', '0.7294', '0.44%']
['Aug 19, 2018', '0.7308', '0.7316', '0.7317', '0.7308', '-0.05%']
['Aug 17, 2018', '0.7312', '0.7261', '0.7321', '0.7253', '0.70%']
['Aug 16, 2018', '0.7261', '0.7240', '0.7288', '0.7222', '0.30%']
['Aug 15, 2018', '0.7239', '0.7247', '0.7249', '0.7202', '-0.08%']
['Aug 14, 2018', '0.7245', '0.7270', '0.7284', '0.7222', '-0.33%']
['Aug 13, 2018', '0.7269', '0.7289', '0.7300', '0.7248', '-0.25%']
['Aug 12, 2018', '0.7287', '0.7278', '0.7300', '0.7273', '-0.21%']
['Aug 10, 2018', '0.7302', '0.7372', '0.7381', '0.7279', '-0.95%']
['Aug 09, 2018', '0.7372', '0.7435', '0.7456', '0.7371', '-0.81%']
['Aug 08, 2018', '0.7432', '0.7420', '0.7440', '0.7382', '0.15%']
['Aug 07, 2018', '0.7421', '0.7386', '0.7440', '0.7379', '0.46%']
['Aug 06, 2018', '0.7387', '0.7398', '0.7406', '0.7372', '-0.09%']
['Aug 05, 2018', '0.7394', '0.7397', '0.7400', '0.7394', '-0.08%']
['Aug 03, 2018', '0.7400', '0.7359', '0.7412', '0.7346', '0.54%']
['Aug 02, 2018', '0.7360', '0.7405', '0.7413', '0.7354', '-0.59%']
['Aug 01, 2018', '0.7404', '0.7427', '0.7430', '0.7389', '-0.34%']
['Jul 31, 2018', '0.7429', '0.7408', '0.7442', '0.7402', '0.30%']
['Jul 30, 2018', '0.7407', '0.7390', '0.7416', '0.7387', '0.12%']
['Jul 29, 2018', '0.7398', '0.7400', '0.7406', '0.7398', '-0.04%']
['Jul 27, 2018', '0.7401', '0.7377', '0.7416', '0.7369', '0.31%']
['Jul 26, 2018', '0.7378', '0.7456', '0.7464', '0.7370', '-1.03%']
['Jul 25, 2018', '0.7455', '0.7424', '0.7466', '0.7391', '0.46%']
```

Many thanks!
OM.

Comment: Why are you using `"tr + tr"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector `tr + tr` means "a tr that's after a tr". So the first row doesn't show up because you're specifically asking for it not to show up. If you want to select all the rows, just select plain `tr`.

If you don't know how selectors work, and just copied this from some other code that seemed close, read [the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors).

If you were trying to do this because there's a `tr` inside the `th` and you wanted to skip that one, this is not the way to do it.

You could try to come up with a complicated selector for every `tr` that's either *before or after* another `tr` (and hope you never run into a one-row table…), or something like that.

But, more simply, just select every `tr` that's inside a `tbody`.

```
for row in table.select('tbody tr'):
```

… or directly inside:

```
for row in table.select('tbody > tr'):
```

Or just select all the rows inside the `tbody` inside of inside the table:

```
for row in table.tbody.select('tr'):
```